# Error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" with scales::rescale

Tags: r

Lots of question with this error - none relevant that I can see.

I have a vector with most values around ±1e9, and `scales::rescale` seems unable to handle it.

```
require(rescale)
x2 = rescale(x)
# Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) return(rep(mean(to),  : 
#   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
# In addition: Warning message:
# In x[1] - x[2] : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Other checks:

```
class(x)
# [1] "integer"

length(x)
# [1] 327117

summary(x)
#       Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
# -1.265e+09 -1.113e+09  1.025e+09  4.160e+08  1.034e+09  1.116e+09 

range(x)
# [1] -1265205248  1116145571

summary(is.na(x))
#    Mode   FALSE    NA's 
# logical  327117       0

plot(sort(x), pch = '.')
```

[image]

No invalid values it seems.  I've recreated a similar range/size dataset with `seq()` that doesn't kill `rescale`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It warns against integer overflow. I would try `rescale(as.numeric(x))`. Please provide a reproducible example for testing.